# indexOf me retorna -1 al utilizarlo en una lista con propiedad

Tags: java, android

Estoy tratando de obtener el índice de una lista con propiedad pero indexOf no encuentra el valor y retorna -1, la lista en la que se realiza la búsqueda contiene propiedades.

```
public class ClasificasionListaPerdida
{
    public double perdidaTabla;
    public ClasificasionListaPerdida(double perd)
    {
        perdidaTabla = perd;
    }
}

public class Listas
{
    public void ListaPerdida()
    {
        listaPerdida = new ArrayList<ClasificasionListaPerdida>();
        listaPerdida.add(new ClasificasionListaPerdida(10.0));
        listaPerdida.add(new ClasificasionListaPerdida(9.0));
        listaPerdida.add(new ClasificasionListaPerdida(8.0));
        listaPerdida.add(new ClasificasionListaPerdida(7.0));
        listaPerdida.add(new ClasificasionListaPerdida(6.0));
        listaPerdida.add(new ClasificasionListaPerdida(5.0));
        listaPerdida.add(new ClasificasionListaPerdida(4.0));
        //.
        //.
        //.
    }
}

double perdidaEstatica = 7.0; //Valor de prueba
for (ClasificasionListaPerdida itemPerd: Listas.listaPerdida)
        {
            if (itemPerd.perdidaTabla < perdidaEstatica)
            {
                double perdidaInferior = itemPerd.perdidaTabla; //Obtiene el valor de 6.0 en este ejemplo
                int indexInferior = Listas.listaPerdida.indexOf(perdidaInferior);
                 //retorna -1, debería retornar 4, que es la posición del valor 6.0
            }
        }
```

No sé si esto se deba a que estoy utilizando el indexOf en lista con propiedad.
Incluso utilizo valores directos como Listas.listaPerdida.indexOf(6.0) y retorna -1.

Comment: Tu lista es una lista de ClasificasionListaPerdida y le estas pidiendo que busque un valor. Como deberia hacerlo? deberias pasarle (si se puede) una funcion que diga como hacer la busqueda...

Comment: Agrega por favor tu clase ClasificasionListaPerdida

Comment: @Jorgesys la clase ClasificasionListaPerdida, si esta es la primera, si a eso te refieres.

Comment: @Ariel ok lo que deseas es obtener el índice cuando itemPerd.perdidaTabla < perdidaEstatica , revisa mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que deseas es obtener el índice cuando `itemPerd.perdidaTabla < perdidaEstatica`, para esto no debes usar indexOf() ya que este método devuelve el índice pero dentro del objeto String que realiza la llamada.

Simplemente puedes usar una variable que determine el índice:

```
int índice = 0;
double perdidaEstatica = 7.0; //Valor de prueba
for (ClasificasionListaPerdida itemPerd: Listas.listaPerdida)
        {
            if (itemPerd.perdidaTabla < perdidaEstatica)
            {
                //double perdidaInferior = itemPerd.perdidaTabla; //Obtiene el valor de 6.0 en este ejemplo
                int indexInferior = índice; 
                 
            }
        índice++;
        }
```

Lo anterior es la forma de encontrar en una lista de objetos, podrías utilizar directamente `indexOf()` pero únicamente si la lista es de tipo Double, ejemplo:

```
    List<Double> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    numbers.add(2.0);
    numbers.add(4.0);
    numbers.add(5.0);
    numbers.add(1.0);
    numbers.add(6.0);
    numbers.add(7.0);
    int index = numbers.indexOf(6.0); 
    System.out.println("El indice es: " + index);
```

tendrías como salida:

```
El indice es: 4
```

Comment: Gracias @Jorgesys, de un principio iba hacerlo así, pero pensé que existía una forma más técnica, para obtener el índice, pero lo realizare de esta forma por el momento. Sobre lo que mencionas del indexOf que devuelve el índice dentro de un objeto Sting, también lo hace con lista genéricas tipo int, double, etc., pero cuando la lista es de tipo de una clase retorna -1.

Comment: @Ariel esta es la única forma de encontrar el indice, a menos que la lista fuera de elementos tipo Double, si podrías hacer uso de este método, revisa la edición de mi respuesta.